# Create Sql server 2008 Huge database script

Tags: sql-server

I have a about 250 SQL script files included tables, stored procedure, user define function, triggers scripts.
I use these files to create and update old database. i want to enhance the time of creation cause it takes very long time to complete. is there more efficient way to create new database with all needed script indexes, triggers, views, SP, UDF.. or way  to speed up the creation time.

Comment: Is backup/restore not an option? For example: if you created a blank database that is pre-loaded with tables, etc.

Comment: backup / restore is a nice solution but it's not suitable for the case of just update some scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the scripts into a New SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio and do a 'Deploy' of the Database Projects after setting up the connection strings properly.

See:

1. [How to: Import Database Objects from a Script.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833195%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and
2. [Creating A Sql Server Database Project In Visual Studio 2012.](http://candordeveloper.com/2013/01/08/creating-a-sql-server-database-project-in-visual-studio-2012/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx)? These tools allow you to point your Visual Studio solution at a DB instance and it will generate you a Diff file, based on your DB projects contents.

Comment: i execute script from c++ project using ado.

Comment: @Mahmoud: So you are dynamically building the script from ADO ?

Comment: i just execute the create script after loading form files in ADO command.